# What does the priest say when offering prasad?

Tags: rituals, prasad

I understand that the prasad is offered 6 times and the priest says something each time. It sounds like:

Om Apanaaya Swahaa,
Om Udanaaya Swahaa,
...,
...,
...,
Om Bramhane Swahaa.

Can someone give the definitive chant for this?

Comment: Those are rituals associated with offering food (naivedya) to deity. They say Pranaya swaha, Apanaya .... vyanaya ... udanaya  samanaya and at last say Om Brahmane swaha. To remember this set up I use the code PAVUS B. Then they also show the mudras related with each mudra. Like when they chant pranaya swaha they show the Prana mudra etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few mantras and mudrAs associated with the ritual of offering Bhoga (food) to deity.

Various books detail the procedure like Nityotsva, ShAktAnanda Tarangini or even in Nitya Karma PujA PrakAsh.

I'm quoting from Anhika Krityam, 3rd Khandam by ShyAmAcharan SharmA (better known as ShyAmAcharan Kaviratna VAridhi).

The procedure is as follows:

> First we have to draw either a triangular or a square mandala with
>   water on the spot the naivedya plate is to be placed.
>
> vam etasmai sopakaranAnnAya namaha - sprinkle water on the food once.
>
> Chanting mula mantra (of that particular deity) and saying Idam
>   sopakarnAnnam Om amukdevatAyAi namah sprinkle water again once on the
>   food.
>
> By saying Om amritapastaranamasi swAhA sprinkle some water on the
>   ground.

Now, comes the role of the GrAsa Mantras and MudrAs.

> On the left hand we have to form a cup like posture that is called the
>   GrAsa mudrA and then chant Om PrAnAya SwAhA (showing PrAna mudra at
>   the same time with the right hand), Om ApAnAya SwAhA (showing ApAna
>   mudrA alongwith with the right hand), Om VyAnAya SwAhA,  Om UdAnAya
>   SwAhA, Om SamAnAya SwAhA and the Om Brahmane SwAhA.
>
> Thereafter we have to Om AmritapidhAnamasi SwAhA and flow some water
>   into the ground.

Now, slight variations may creep in if we are following different traditions and scriptures. For example, the MahAnirvAna Tantram mentions the order of showing the MudrAs (and of course chanting the Mantras) slightly differently.

> Then, after recitation of the Mula-Mantra seven times, it should be
>   oftered to the Devi with the water taken from the vessel of offering
>   (90). The worshipper, after reciting the Mula-Mantra, should say:
>   "This cooked food, with all other necessaries, I offer to the
>   Adya-Kali, my Ishta-devi." He should then say: "O Shiva! partake of
>   this offering" (91). **Then he should make the Devi eat the offering
>   by means of the five Mudras called Prana, Apana, Samana, Vyana, and
>   Udana** (90).
>
> **Chapter 6**

So, here we have to chant the following Mantras while showing the five MudrAs during offering food to the deity:

Om PrAnAya SwAhA, apAnAya swAhA, SamanAya SwAhA, VyAnAya SwAhA and UdAnAya SwAhA.